# cpp-ethereum not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed. (Chocolatey)

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, chocolatey

I would like to install `cpp-ethereum` following the [documentation](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/windows-chocolatey.html)

Powershell is running in admin mode, but if I try to run the install command (`choco install cpp-ethereum`), I get this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco install cpp-ethereum
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Installing the following packages:
cpp-ethereum
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
cpp-ethereum not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but t
he version does not.
 Version: ""
 Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - cpp-ethereum - cpp-ethereum not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but t
he version does not.
 Version: ""
 Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"
```

The same error message can be found in the log. What does this error message mean and how is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this error message mean and how is it possible to fix it?

It means the package does not exist.

So you can either use Ethminer which gets it's origins from cpp-ethereum or download the source to cpp-ethereum then use that.  It also appears that: [AlethZero Stable 0.8.2.3-POC8](https://chocolatey.org/packages/AlethZero-Stable/0.8.2.3-POC8) is a compiled version of cpp-ethereum.  Of course that particular project has not received a single update in 3 years.

> The ethminer is an Ethereum GPU mining worker. It origins in
>   cpp-ethereum project (where GPU mining has been discontinued). Then
>   hugely improved in Genoil's fork.

[ethminer 0.11.0](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ethminer)

Here is how I know it doesn't exist:

> Search for "cpp-ethereum" returned 0 packages

[Source](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=cpp-ethereum)

Going directly to the package url also doesn't show a package:

[Cpp-Ethereum](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cpp-ethereum)

> it possible to fix it?

If you can find another Chocolatey source I suppose you could add it and then install it or you can just compile from source or use something else but otherwise you cannot fix it because the package no longer exists.

You can also maintain your own package internally and/or on the community package repository.

*The provided link in your question, clearly indicates, they have not supported Chocolatey in a very long time (if ever).*

Comment: As a clarification point - the package was not removed by the moderators/community, it never existed. You could go directly to the package page at https://chocolatey.org/packages/cpp-ethereum and see a hidden package if it existed. There isn't one.

Comment: @ferventcoder - I am not sure it really matters.  It doesn't exist today.  So an alternative must be used if the author wants to use Chocolatey to install a similar package.

Comment: I just wanted to be clear on that one point. I read the link, and I don't know if the group ever maintained a Chocolatey package on the community repository. If they did, it certainly wasn't under the name `cpp-ethereum`. One by that name never existed - one named `ethereum` was submitted by a community member but it never made it past moderation. So I'm not really sure what they meant by "though we have done so in the past."

Comment: @ferventcoder - Understood.  Adding the clarification it never existed just isn't a huge priority when it does not really make a difference to my actual answer.

Comment: I did provide an edit - the edit also points out that the OP can create and maintain an internal package and that they can also make a package available on the community package repository if they would like to do that as well - two additional options for fixing the issue.